How to calculate new, retained, lost customers in a given time period in Looker Studio
Let's say I have order data with customer name, order dollar amount, order date.
I want to create a chart in looker studio that always looks at the rolling latest 24 weeks and I am trying to determine the following:

New customer dollars (dollars from customers that haven't ordered prior to the beginning of that rolling 24 week date range)
Lost customer dollars (dollars from customers that ordered in the past but haven't ordered in the past 24 weeks)
Existing customer dollars gains/loss (dollars from customers that have ordered prior to the past 52 weeks and then also have ordered in the past 24 weeks)

I am pretty experienced in looker but this feels difficult. It feels like you need to do at least a self-join to get the first order date but I'm a little stuck from there.
Any help would be appreciated.

Hi. StackOverflow is for helping with code issues, not for implementing stuff from a spec, there are other sites for that. BR

The short answer is you can't with the fields you have selected. Looker Studio is a visualization tool and not a BI tool, it can not process data in the same way as power bi or even excel. technically using blend with min and max order dates so possible but looker will really struggle with more than a couple of hounded records. You are far better off transforming the data before it goes into looker studio and adding the columns for first and last order date and then it all becomes simple.
